# Why do I get Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use [this](https://github.com/dodo/node-slug) package. I've added these `console.log`'s at the beginning of the slug function.

```
function slug(string, opts) {
    console.log('log 1: -------');
    console.log('log 2: ' + string);
    console.log('log 3: ' + typeof string);
    string = string.toString();
    ....
 }
```

Here is the output:

```
log 1: -------
log 2: Yüzey Aktif Maddeler
log 3: string
/Users/------/seeder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:99
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at slug (/Users/------/seeder/node_modules/slug/slug.js:16:20)
    at Object.createSlug (/Users/------/seeder/seeder/utils.js:4:9)
    at getContent (/Users/------/seeder/seeder/content-seeder.js:345:22)
    at topic.contents.forEach.content (/Users/------/seeder/seeder/content-seeder.js:425:31)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /Users/------/seeder/seeder/content-seeder.js:424:21
    at /Users/------/seeder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:523:5
    at /Users/------/seeder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:701:5
    at handleCallback (/Users/------/seeder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:56)
    at executeCommands (/Users/------/seeder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:405:12)
```

Even if type of string parameter is a string, `string.toString()` throws a TypeError. It says string is undefined.

I'm not an experienced js developer. Why would this happen?

Edit:
I call it from this function

```
function getContent(content, categoryId) {
    console.log(content.topicVideo);
    return {
        // _id: Random.id(),
        // other properties
        contentSlug: slug(content.topicVideo.contentName, {
            lower: true
        })
    };
}
```

New logs:

```
{ id: '197505065',
  categorySort: 18,
  categoryName: 'Hayatımızda Kimya',
  contentSort: 2,
  contentName: 'Yüzey Aktif Maddeler',
  fileName: 'KonuAnlatimi.mp4' }
```

Edit:

I've added a log at the end of the slug function.

```
    console.log(result);
    return result;
};
```

This prints the results and then throws error.

```
log 1: -------
log 2: Yüzey Aktif Maddeler
log 3: string
log 4: Yüzey Aktif Maddeler
yuzey-aktif-maddeler
```

Edit: I think this line gives a hint:

```
/Users/------/seeder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:99
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
```

I think it logs correct string, but fails on undefined one without logging the logs. Is this possible? I've found out that one of content.topicVideo.contentName is actually undefined. But error is thrown without logging it. Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you sure it's throwing at that exact line ? Can you reproduce the problem in a code snippet?

Comment: Yes. I've checked the line numbers

Comment: This shouldn't happen, you need to provide a more complete example, otherwise we can't really help you.

Comment: Yes, the example you've given doesn't throw an error: https://jsfiddle.net/rs5eocbt/

Comment: I don't know how can I clarify the example. And I don't think I can reproduce the problem. I've edited the question. I know this shouldn't happen.

Comment: The code works fine if "Yüzey Aktif Maddeler" is passed as first parameter to the function. But if null or undefined is passed to the function then it will throw an exception "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

Comment: Yes it doesn't and it shouldn't throw an error in a simple code snippet. @Stu

Comment: Why are you converting with toString if typeof reveals that it is a string type already?

Comment: It's not me. It's author of the package. I think it's needed when first parameter is not a string. @SebCooper

Comment: You should not use string as a variable name because it is a reserved name (a type). Try to change the name of the parameter in your function to e.g name.

Comment: So this slug function code is from the node module used - and therefore should not be changed?

Comment: I might change it but I want to understand why would this happen. And it doesn't happen always. I throws the error on the first execution, but it doesn't on the next. This is stupid! Or I am crazy

Comment: Changing the parameter name didn't help @John

Comment: Have you tried passing an object as the first parameter as a test?

Comment: I tried as you said it. It didn't throw error. But how does it help?

Comment: Try updating your version of the node module: see https://github.com/dodo/node-slug/blob/master/slug.js
It looks like your code is out of date.

Comment: No it's not. I'm using 0.9.1

Comment: would be nice if you accept any of the answers, if they solve your problem.

Comment: no they didn't. sorry @fuma

Answer (score 28):

To make sure that .toString() doesn't throw an error, you could:

```
string = "" + string; // amends the value to an string, even if its undefined or null etc
```

instead of:

```
string = string.toString();
```

However you could also check if the value of string is undefined or null.
Also see [here](http://www.2ality.com/2012/03/converting-to-string.html).

Comment: This is a widely used npm module. I don't want to change the code

Comment: Well it's on you, but at least I would recommend a check for null or undefined if it would throw errors.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should check if string has a falsy value and(optionally if it is not a string)

```
function slug(string, opts) {
    console.log('log 1: -------');
    console.log('log 2: ' + string);
    console.log('log 3: ' + typeof string);
    if(string)
        string = string.toString();
    ....
 }
```

From MDN:

> ## Falsy
>
> A falsy value is a value that translates to false when evaluated in a Boolean context.

More about falsy values in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 2):

The following code works fine (added slug.js module into the script to test). Perhaps this will help you analyze your code?

```js
(function (root) {
// lazy require symbols table
var _symbols, removelist;
function symbols(code) {
    if (_symbols) return _symbols[code];
    _symbols = require('unicode/category/So');
    removelist = ['sign','cross','of','symbol','staff','hand','black','white']
        .map(function (word) {return new RegExp(word, 'gi')});
    return _symbols[code];
}

function slug(string, opts) {
    string = string.toString();
    if ('string' === typeof opts)
        opts = {replacement:opts};
    opts = opts || {};
    opts.mode = opts.mode || slug.defaults.mode;
    var defaults = slug.defaults.modes[opts.mode];
    var keys = ['replacement','multicharmap','charmap','remove','lower'];
    for (var key, i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) { key = keys[i];
        opts[key] = (key in opts) ? opts[key] : defaults[key];
    }
    if ('undefined' === typeof opts.symbols)
        opts.symbols = defaults.symbols;

    var lengths = [];
    for (var key in opts.multicharmap) {
        if (!opts.multicharmap.hasOwnProperty(key))
            continue;

        var len = key.length;
        if (lengths.indexOf(len) === -1)
            lengths.push(len);
    }

    var code, unicode, result = "";
    for (var char, i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; i++) { char = string[i];
        if (!lengths.some(function (len) {
            var str = string.substr(i, len);
            if (opts.multicharmap[str]) {
                i += len - 1;
                char = opts.multicharmap[str];
                return true;
            } else return false;
        })) {
            if (opts.charmap[char]) {
                char = opts.charmap[char];
                code = char.charCodeAt(0);
            } else {
                code = string.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            if (opts.symbols && (unicode = symbols(code))) {
                char = unicode.name.toLowerCase();
                for(var j = 0, rl = removelist.length; j < rl; j++) {
                    char = char.replace(removelist[j], '');
                }
                char = char.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            }
        }
        char = char.replace(/[^\w\s\-\.\_~]/g, ''); // allowed
        if (opts.remove) char = char.replace(opts.remove, ''); // add flavour
        result += char;
    }
    result = result.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim leading/trailing spaces
    result = result.replace(/[-\s]+/g, opts.replacement); // convert spaces
    result = result.replace(opts.replacement+"$",''); // remove trailing separator
    if (opts.lower)
      result = result.toLowerCase();
    return result;
};

slug.defaults = {
    mode: 'pretty',
};

slug.multicharmap = slug.defaults.multicharmap = {
    '<3': 'love', '&&': 'and', '||': 'or', 'w/': 'with',
};

// https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/media/js/urlify.js
slug.charmap  = slug.defaults.charmap = {
    // latin
    'À': 'A', 'Á': 'A', 'Â': 'A', 'Ã': 'A', 'Ä': 'A', 'Å': 'A', 'Æ': 'AE',
    'Ç': 'C', 'È': 'E', 'É': 'E', 'Ê': 'E', 'Ë': 'E', 'Ì': 'I', 'Í': 'I',
    'Î': 'I', 'Ï': 'I', 'Ð': 'D', 'Ñ': 'N', 'Ò': 'O', 'Ó': 'O', 'Ô': 'O',
    'Õ': 'O', 'Ö': 'O', 'Ő': 'O', 'Ø': 'O', 'Ù': 'U', 'Ú': 'U', 'Û': 'U',
    'Ü': 'U', 'Ű': 'U', 'Ý': 'Y', 'Þ': 'TH', 'ß': 'ss', 'à':'a', 'á':'a',
    'â': 'a', 'ã': 'a', 'ä': 'a', 'å': 'a', 'æ': 'ae', 'ç': 'c', 'è': 'e',
    'é': 'e', 'ê': 'e', 'ë': 'e', 'ì': 'i', 'í': 'i', 'î': 'i', 'ï': 'i',
    'ð': 'd', 'ñ': 'n', 'ò': 'o', 'ó': 'o', 'ô': 'o', 'õ': 'o', 'ö': 'o',
    'ő': 'o', 'ø': 'o', 'ù': 'u', 'ú': 'u', 'û': 'u', 'ü': 'u', 'ű': 'u',
    'ý': 'y', 'þ': 'th', 'ÿ': 'y', 'ẞ': 'SS',
    // greek
    'α':'a', 'β':'b', 'γ':'g', 'δ':'d', 'ε':'e', 'ζ':'z', 'η':'h', 'θ':'8',
    'ι':'i', 'κ':'k', 'λ':'l', 'μ':'m', 'ν':'n', 'ξ':'3', 'ο':'o', 'π':'p',
    'ρ':'r', 'σ':'s', 'τ':'t', 'υ':'y', 'φ':'f', 'χ':'x', 'ψ':'ps', 'ω':'w',
    'ά':'a', 'έ':'e', 'ί':'i', 'ό':'o', 'ύ':'y', 'ή':'h', 'ώ':'w', 'ς':'s',
    'ϊ':'i', 'ΰ':'y', 'ϋ':'y', 'ΐ':'i',
    'Α':'A', 'Β':'B', 'Γ':'G', 'Δ':'D', 'Ε':'E', 'Ζ':'Z', 'Η':'H', 'Θ':'8',
    'Ι':'I', 'Κ':'K', 'Λ':'L', 'Μ':'M', 'Ν':'N', 'Ξ':'3', 'Ο':'O', 'Π':'P',
    'Ρ':'R', 'Σ':'S', 'Τ':'T', 'Υ':'Y', 'Φ':'F', 'Χ':'X', 'Ψ':'PS', 'Ω':'W',
    'Ά':'A', 'Έ':'E', 'Ί':'I', 'Ό':'O', 'Ύ':'Y', 'Ή':'H', 'Ώ':'W', 'Ϊ':'I',
    'Ϋ':'Y',
    // turkish
    'ş':'s', 'Ş':'S', 'ı':'i', 'İ':'I',
    'ğ':'g', 'Ğ':'G',
    // russian
    'а':'a', 'б':'b', 'в':'v', 'г':'g', 'д':'d', 'е':'e', 'ё':'yo', 'ж':'zh',
    'з':'z', 'и':'i', 'й':'j', 'к':'k', 'л':'l', 'м':'m', 'н':'n', 'о':'o',
    'п':'p', 'р':'r', 'с':'s', 'т':'t', 'у':'u', 'ф':'f', 'х':'h', 'ц':'c',
    'ч':'ch', 'ш':'sh', 'щ':'sh', 'ъ':'u', 'ы':'y', 'ь':'', 'э':'e', 'ю':'yu',
    'я':'ya',
    'А':'A', 'Б':'B', 'В':'V', 'Г':'G', 'Д':'D', 'Е':'E', 'Ё':'Yo', 'Ж':'Zh',
    'З':'Z', 'И':'I', 'Й':'J', 'К':'K', 'Л':'L', 'М':'M', 'Н':'N', 'О':'O',
    'П':'P', 'Р':'R', 'С':'S', 'Т':'T', 'У':'U', 'Ф':'F', 'Х':'H', 'Ц':'C',
    'Ч':'Ch', 'Ш':'Sh', 'Щ':'Sh', 'Ъ':'U', 'Ы':'Y', 'Ь':'', 'Э':'E', 'Ю':'Yu',
    'Я':'Ya',
    // ukranian
    'Є':'Ye', 'І':'I', 'Ї':'Yi', 'Ґ':'G', 'є':'ye', 'і':'i', 'ї':'yi', 'ґ':'g',
    // czech
    'č':'c', 'ď':'d', 'ě':'e', 'ň': 'n', 'ř':'r', 'š':'s', 'ť':'t', 'ů':'u',
    'ž':'z', 'Č':'C', 'Ď':'D', 'Ě':'E', 'Ň': 'N', 'Ř':'R', 'Š':'S', 'Ť':'T',
    'Ů':'U', 'Ž':'Z',
    // polish
    'ą':'a', 'ć':'c', 'ę':'e', 'ł':'l', 'ń':'n', 'ś':'s', 'ź':'z',
    'ż':'z', 'Ą':'A', 'Ć':'C', 'Ę':'E', 'Ł':'L', 'Ń':'N', 'Ś':'S',
    'Ź':'Z', 'Ż':'Z',
    // latvian
    'ā':'a', 'ē':'e', 'ģ':'g', 'ī':'i', 'ķ':'k', 'ļ':'l', 'ņ':'n',
    'ū':'u', 'Ā':'A', 'Ē':'E', 'Ģ':'G', 'Ī':'I',
    'Ķ':'K', 'Ļ':'L', 'Ņ':'N', 'Ū':'U',
    // lithuanian
    'ė':'e', 'į':'i', 'ų':'u', 'Ė': 'E', 'Į': 'I', 'Ų':'U',
    // romanian
    'ț':'t', 'Ț':'T', 'ţ':'t', 'Ţ':'T', 'ș':'s', 'Ș':'S', 'ă':'a', 'Ă':'A',
    // vietnamese
    'Ạ': 'A', 'Ả': 'A', 'Ầ': 'A', 'Ấ': 'A', 'Ậ': 'A', 'Ẩ': 'A', 'Ẫ': 'A',
    'Ằ': 'A', 'Ắ': 'A', 'Ặ': 'A', 'Ẳ': 'A', 'Ẵ': 'A', 'Ẹ': 'E', 'Ẻ': 'E',
    'Ẽ': 'E', 'Ề': 'E', 'Ế': 'E', 'Ệ': 'E', 'Ể': 'E', 'Ễ': 'E', 'Ị': 'I',
    'Ỉ': 'I', 'Ĩ': 'I', 'Ọ': 'O', 'Ỏ': 'O', 'Ồ': 'O', 'Ố': 'O', 'Ộ': 'O',
    'Ổ': 'O', 'Ỗ': 'O', 'Ơ': 'O', 'Ờ': 'O', 'Ớ': 'O', 'Ợ': 'O', 'Ở': 'O',
    'Ỡ': 'O', 'Ụ': 'U', 'Ủ': 'U', 'Ũ': 'U', 'Ư': 'U', 'Ừ': 'U', 'Ứ': 'U',
    'Ự': 'U', 'Ử': 'U', 'Ữ': 'U', 'Ỳ': 'Y', 'Ỵ': 'Y', 'Ỷ': 'Y', 'Ỹ': 'Y',
    'Đ': 'D', 'ạ': 'a', 'ả': 'a', 'ầ': 'a', 'ấ': 'a', 'ậ': 'a', 'ẩ': 'a',
    'ẫ': 'a', 'ằ': 'a', 'ắ': 'a', 'ặ': 'a', 'ẳ': 'a', 'ẵ': 'a', 'ẹ': 'e',
    'ẻ': 'e', 'ẽ': 'e', 'ề': 'e', 'ế': 'e', 'ệ': 'e', 'ể': 'e', 'ễ': 'e',
    'ị': 'i', 'ỉ': 'i', 'ĩ': 'i', 'ọ': 'o', 'ỏ': 'o', 'ồ': 'o', 'ố': 'o',
    'ộ': 'o', 'ổ': 'o', 'ỗ': 'o', 'ơ': 'o', 'ờ': 'o', 'ớ': 'o', 'ợ': 'o',
    'ở': 'o', 'ỡ': 'o', 'ụ': 'u', 'ủ': 'u', 'ũ': 'u', 'ư': 'u', 'ừ': 'u',
    'ứ': 'u', 'ự': 'u', 'ử': 'u', 'ữ': 'u', 'ỳ': 'y', 'ỵ': 'y', 'ỷ': 'y',
    'ỹ': 'y', 'đ': 'd',
    // currency
    '€': 'euro', '₢': 'cruzeiro', '₣': 'french franc', '£': 'pound',
    '₤': 'lira', '₥': 'mill', '₦': 'naira', '₧': 'peseta', '₨': 'rupee',
    '₩': 'won', '₪': 'new shequel', '₫': 'dong', '₭': 'kip', '₮': 'tugrik',
    '₯': 'drachma', '₰': 'penny', '₱': 'peso', '₲': 'guarani', '₳': 'austral',
    '₴': 'hryvnia', '₵': 'cedi', '¢': 'cent', '¥': 'yen', '元': 'yuan',
    '円': 'yen', '﷼': 'rial', '₠': 'ecu', '¤': 'currency', '฿': 'baht',
    "$": 'dollar', '₹': 'indian rupee',
    // symbols
    '©':'(c)', 'œ': 'oe', 'Œ': 'OE', '∑': 'sum', '®': '(r)', '†': '+',
    '“': '"', '”': '"', '‘': "'", '’': "'", '∂': 'd', 'ƒ': 'f', '™': 'tm',
    '℠': 'sm', '…': '...', '˚': 'o', 'º': 'o', 'ª': 'a', '•': '*',
    '∆': 'delta', '∞': 'infinity', '♥': 'love', '&': 'and', '|': 'or',
    '<': 'less', '>': 'greater',
};

slug.defaults.modes = {
    rfc3986: {
        replacement: '-',
        symbols: true,
        remove: null,
        lower: true,
        charmap: slug.defaults.charmap,
        multicharmap: slug.defaults.multicharmap,
    },
    pretty: {
        replacement: '-',
        symbols: true,
        remove: /[.]/g,
        lower: false,
        charmap: slug.defaults.charmap,
        multicharmap: slug.defaults.multicharmap,
    },
};

// Be compatible with different module systems

if (typeof define !== 'undefined' && define.amd) { // AMD
    // dont load symbols table in the browser
    for (var key in slug.defaults.modes) {
        if (!slug.defaults.modes.hasOwnProperty(key))
            continue;

        slug.defaults.modes[key].symbols = false;
    }
    define([], function () {return slug});
} else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { // CommonJS
    symbols(); // preload symbols table
    module.exports = slug;
} else { // Script tag
    // dont load symbols table in the browser
    for (var key in slug.defaults.modes) {
        if (!slug.defaults.modes.hasOwnProperty(key))
            continue;

        slug.defaults.modes[key].symbols = false;
    }
    root.slug = slug;
}

}(this));

var content = {
 'topicVideo': { 
   'id': '197505065',
    'categorySort': 18,
    'categoryName': 'Hayatımızda Kimya',
    'contentSort': 2,
    'contentName': 'Yüzey Aktif Maddeler',
    'fileName': 'KonuAnlatimi.mp4' 
  }
}

function getContent(content, categoryId) {
    console.log(content.topicVideo);
    return {
        // _id: Random.id(),
        // other properties
        contentSlug: slug(content.topicVideo.contentName, undefined)
    };
}

console.log(getContent(content, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
function slug(string, opts) {
    console.log('log 1: -------');
    console.log('log 2: ' + string);
    console.log('log 3: ' + typeof string);
    string = String(string);
    ....
 }
```